# Close Tab automatically in Service Cloud Console

Tags: javascript, consoleintegrationtoolkit, service-console

I have a script which opens a new page in a new sub-tab on the Service Cloud Console, and another one that closes that same new page once it's done loading.

It works, but I need to click on the '< a >' element to get it running, how can I make it run automatically?

Here's what I got so far:

```
<apex:page >
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/28.0/integration.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/35.0/integration.js"/>


<A HREF="#" onClick="testCloseTab();return false">
  Click here to open a console URL</A> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
/*This script opens the article in a new sub-tub*/

    if (typeof(srcUp) == 'function') {
     srcUp('/articles/en_US/Procedure/BSOD');
     testCloseTab();
   }
else{
 window.open('/articles/en_US/Procedure/BSOD');
 testCloseTab();
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
/*This script closes this VF page*/
 var callback = function () {
   if (result.error) {
    alert("Error message is " + result.error);
  }
};
function testCloseTab() {
            //First find the ID of the current tab to close it
            sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(closeSubtab);
          }

          var closeSubtab = function closeSubtab(result) {
            //Now that we have the tab ID, we can close it
            var tabId = result.id;
            sforce.console.closeTab(tabId, callback);
          };
 </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I think you can use something similar to this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388380/capture-the-close-event-of-popup-window-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a [workaround](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000957DIAQ) suggested in SFDC Developer Forum by Ron Wild.